The labels option "categorized" is not appearing in the properties' label tab
I have a fairly simple vector layer with the boundaries of federal, state, private, and tribal owned land. I want to color code based on these attributes, but when I go to the properties for that layer, and then into the labels tab, then the dropdown menu, the option called "categorized" isn't appearing. The options it is giving me are "no labels" "single labels" "rule-based labeling" and "blocking". I'm using QGIS 3.28.
I'm wondering why it is not appearing, and if it can be fixed, how?

As commented by @BenW:

You're in the wrong tab. You want the Symbology tab, not Labels.

